# Assign my own /24 address to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I'm currently renting a /24 address block and would like to assign an IP Address from that block to one of my EC2 instances. I heard from a friend a while back that this can be done, but I haven't yet found a way to do it using Elastic IP or through an EC2 instances IP settings.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? You should use DNS names and avoid hard-coding IP addresses.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please see my comment below

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to bring your own range of Public IP address to AWS.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I'm using AWS to set up a cloud security platform as the product for my company. However, services like Netflix have AWS IP ranges blacklisted due to people using AWS VPNs to access other countries' content. The most intuitive way is to add our own IP address blocks to AWS so the IP Address is signed by us on lookup so services know it's legit. We also using LeaseWeb which supports this behavior, but I was hoping AWS would as well.